# Taylor coefficients of Hadamard product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series

I imagine this to be a very classical question in complex analysis:

Consider the Hadamard product

$$g(\mu) =  \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}E_1(\mu z_n),$$
where $E_1(z):=(1-z)e^z$ is the first elementary factor
for some sequence $z_n \to 0$ fast enough, such that $g$ is entire. In fact, choosing $ (z_m)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ to be square-summable is sufficient.

I wonder if there are any estimates on the Taylor coefficients of $g$ known?

I can only think of the following very pedestrian approach:
Using the elementary inequality $$\left\lvert (1-w)e^w \right\rvert \le e^{\vert w \vert^2/2},$$

we can estimate
$$\vert g(\mu) \vert  \le  e^{\frac{\vert \mu^2\vert}{2} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \vert z_m \vert^2}=:h(\mu).$$

This implies for the power series $g(\mu) = \sum_n a_n \mu^n$ that
$\vert a_n \vert \le r^{-n} \sup_{\mu = r} h(\mu)$ for any $r.$

Optimizing over $r$ we find that
$$\vert a_n \vert \le \frac{ e^{n/2}\Vert (z_m)_{m \in \mathbb N} \Vert^n_{\ell^2}}{n^{n/2}}.$$

I am wondering if there is a systematic way to improve these estimates of $\vert a_n\vert$ (apart from some obvious improvements such as $g'(0)=0$.

Comment: This does not seem to work for $n = 3$: $h^{(3)}(0) = 0$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Please state your problem more completely: the RHS in your inequality is a complex number. Do you mean that $\mu$ is real? Also, $h'(0)=0$, while $g'(0)$ does not have to be $0$ under your conditions.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki indeed, sorry. I modified it to what I actually wanted to ask.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko indeed, sorry for the confusion. I think when formulating the question I tried to simplify it in a way that made it wrong.

Comment: Oh, now I see, thanks. (Two typos: $g'(0) = 0$, not $g'(\mu) = 0$; and $n$ is used both for the coefficient number in $a_n$, and for the dummy variable in $\|z_n\|_{\ell^2}$.)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki thanks a lot and sorry for the many typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this bound can be improved much, at least for even $n$. Indeed: set $z_1 = z_2 = \ldots = z_k = k^{-1/2}$ and $z_{k+1} = z_{k+2} = \ldots = 0$, so that the $\ell^2$ norm of $(z_n)$ is $1$. (Intuitively, this is the worst-case scenario.) Then
$$ g(\mu) = (E_1(k^{-1/2} \mu))^k = (1 - k^{-1/2} z)^k e^{z \sqrt k} .$$
As $k \to \infty$, the above functions converge to $e^{-z^2/2}$ locally uniformly on $\mathbb C$, and so the $n$th Taylor coefficient of $g$ converges to the $n$th Taylor coefficient of $e^{-z^2/2}$, which is equal to
$$ \frac{1}{2^{n/2} (n/2)!} \approx \frac{e^{n/2}}{n^{(n+1)/2} \sqrt{\pi}} $$
when $n$ is even. Compared to your "pedestrian" bound, this is off by a factor $n^{-1/2}$.

My guess would be that things are not different for odd $n$, but I did not think about it.